# Windows 8.1 keeps changing my boot order in favor of Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a partition of an external disk drive connected to my HP 400-224 PC.  The Ubuntu boot partition is sdb.  EFI mode is enabled for both Ubuntu and Windows 8.1.  Secure boot is enabled; fast boot is disabled; legacy boot is disabled.  When I boot Ubuntu and restart within Ubuntu, grub-efi lets me choose whether I want Ubuntu or Windows.  However, if I go back to Windows and restart, Windows always changes my boot order, placing ubuntu last in the list.  I always have to manually modify my UEFI settings and place Ubuntu ahead of Windows if I want to go back to Ubuntu.  This seems like too much work.  Is there any way to keep Windows from doing this?